# How to get the total count of for each in laravel blade

Tags: laravel

```html
<h3>
    @php $i = 0 @endphp
    @foreach ($dischargePatients as $patient)
        @if ($patient->GetPatientDistrict() == auth()->user()->district_assigned)
            {{ ++$i }}
        @else
            {{ $i }}
        @endif
    @endforeach
</h3>
```

the value i get was "0 0 0" , what i need is 3.
there are actually 4 which 3 is true and 1 false
i hope you understand my question, thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its better to count the users in the patientDistrict in the controller and give the view the new variable

```php
$patientsInDistrict = collect($dischargePatients)
    ->filter(function($patient) {
        return $patient->GetPatientDistrict() == auth()->user()->district_assigned;
    })
    ->count()

...

return view('your-view', ['dischargePatients' => $dischargePatients, 'patientsInDistrict' => $patientsInDistrict]);
```

That gives you a new variable in your view

```
{{ $patientsInDistrict }}
```

Comment: thank you so much. this is a great help , all i need to return was the {{$patientsInDistrict }} on the blade part.